# mod_rewrite: how to enable access to static content and redirect specific url schemes?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My apps' urls are like this: `http://domain.com/projects/project-name/`

My app's file system is like this:

```
htdocs/projects/project-name/
 L index.html
 L img/image1.png
 L img/image2.png
 L img/...
```

I need to send requests like `http://domain.com/projects/project-name/`  to

```
htdocs/index.php?section=$1&item=$2
```

But they display the project-name/index.html file instead.

Here is what i tried:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule . - [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?section=$1&item=$2&%{QUERY_STRING} [NC,L]
```

Obviously, the `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f`rule is the culprit. But i need to let the server serve the static img files. How can I tell it to let all file requests but rewrite the project folder's default index.html?

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Misunderstood the question.

You want to rewrite /projects/project-name/ to index.php?... I am also assuming you'll want to be able to request files from within project-name:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)(/(index[^/]+)?)?$ /index.php?section=$1&item=$2 [QSA,NC,L]
```

If being able to request files from the project-name subdir isn't important, just remove `(/(index[^/]+)?)` and replace it with `/`. The `(/(index[^/]+)?)` assumes your `DirectoryIndex` files start with "index".

Meh.

Consider enabling the mod_rewrite log to analyze how it is applying your conditions and patterns. Within the server or vhost scope (not htaccess) add:

```
LogLevel warn rewrite:trace6
```

The [`LogLevel`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#loglevel) directive can [enable logging for mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#logging) which will be written to your defined `ErrorLog`. trace6 is the highest mod_rewrite log level before you get into hex output. Be sure to comment out or remove LogLevel when you're done.

---

Original, unrelated answer (ignore):

You need to negate files, of which right now you are not, notice the use of `!`:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

Most importantly, your [RewriteCond](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) will not affect your second RewriteRule. It is only applied to the first RewriteRule (in your case `RewriteRule . - [L]`):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?section=$1&item=$2&%{QUERY_STRING} [NC,L]
```

And you may also choose to negate directories:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

I'd also consider using the [`QSA` (query string append)](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa) flag instead of appending `QUERY_STRING`:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?section=$1&item=$2 [QSA,NC,L]
```

In summary:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?section=$1&item=$2 [QSA,NC,L]
```

Comment: I don't think i need to negate file, since it would mean: "if the file does not exist, don't try to rewrite the url" (3rd line in your proposal).
And you say the rewriteCond will not affect my second RewriteRule, but it will, since if it's condition is met, the L flag is thrown up and the request processed, otherwise it continues checking for further rules. Or am i missing something? Thank you, a.

Comment: @pixeline The nature of RewriteCond is that it only affects the first encountered RewriteRule, never any after. `[L]` just means that no subsequent RewriteCond nor RewriteRule (or other mod_rewrite directives) will be processed for the remainder of the request. In regards to `!-f`, it means that "if the requested path is not a file, then perform the following RewriteRule, if not, skip it."

Comment: thank you. Unfortunately, that does not solve the issue: if accessed directly, http://domain.com/section/item/ still displays the http://domain.com/section/item/index.html file, instead of being handled by http://domain.com/index.php

Answer (score 0):

It should work, I am providing a slightly modified version of your rule with complete `.htaccess` to be placed in `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess`:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html

Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?section=$1&item=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks, but the real index.html file is still shown if url is domain.com/section/item/

Comment: To say it more clearly, if accessed directly, http://domain.com/section/item/ still displays the http://domain.com/section/item/index.html file, instead of being handled by http://domain.com/index.php

Comment: For that you will need `DirectoryIndex index.php index.html` where `index.php` appears before `index.html` (see edit). Now from a directory `item` `index.php` will be served first.

Comment: that would have apache look for domain.com/section/item/index.php . I need the mod_rewrite to tell it to look for domain.com/index.php  I think i'll need to make the file directory structure different from the url structure. It's just weird that it works locally but not on the production server.